# Is there a way to merge multiple columns in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, react-table

I have a data array as:

```
data = [ {date: "16/05/2020", value: [ {column: "student", count: 10, value: "abcd" }, 
         {column: "teacher", count: 25, value: "pqrs" }] },
         {date: "17/05/2020", value: [ {column: "student", count: 19, value: "mno" }, 
         {column: "teacher", count: 7, value: "xyz" }] }
        ];
```

This is the column array:

```
columns = [{ Header: "Date", accessor: "date"}, 
           { Header: "Column", accessor: "column"},
           { Header: "Count", accessor: "count"},
           { Header: "Value", accessor: "value"}
           ]
```

I want to display the data as mentioned in the picture ([table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6q2S.png)) in React Table.

Inside render(), I am doing this:

```
              <ReactTable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                minRows={0}
                defaultPageSize={25}
              />
```

Kindly, help.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: is `ReactTable` a 3rd party library?

Comment: Yes, it is a 3rd party library.

Comment: can you add the link to its git repository?

Comment: I have not created git repository yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `accessor` to get into the properties from `data`
and to custom the cells.

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    date: "16/05/2020",
    value: [
      { column: "student", count: 10, value: "abcd" },
      { column: "teacher", count: 25, value: "pqrs" }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: "17/05/2020",
    value: [
      { column: "student", count: 19, value: "mno" },
      { column: "teacher", count: 7, value: "xyz" }
    ]
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Date",
    id: "date",
    accessor: d => (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{d.date}</div>
        <div>{d.date}</div>
      </div>
    )
  },
  {
    Header: "Column",
    id: "column",
    accessor: d => (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{d.value[0].column}</div>
        <div>{d.value[1].column}</div>
      </div>
    )
  },
  {
    Header: "Count",
    id: "count",
    accessor: d => (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{d.value[0].count}</div>
        <div>{d.value[1].count}</div>
      </div>
    )
  },
  {
    Header: "Value",
    id: "value",
    accessor: d => (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{d.value[0].value}</div>
        <div>{d.value[1].value}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} />;
};
```

and here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-matsumoto-757xn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:131-1328):